# How to use non-capturing parenthesis to capture a word or nothing at all?

Tags: regex, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am looking to use two variations of the same step in my ATDD test using cucumber-jvm

> Then order passes quantity limits

and

> Then order passes limits

This will read better with different scenarios. I have tried various variations of the following:

```
@Then(value = "^order passes (?: | quantity )limits$")
public void verifyCreditPassed(){ 
    //Assert stuff
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the `^` and `$` meta-characters then you regex becomes:

```
order passes (?:quantity |)limits
```

because when you use `^` the line must start with the word `order` and because you used `$` the line must end with `limits`, the above regex will match your sentence anywhere inside the input string.

or use the following regex:

```
^Then order passes (?:quantity )?limits$
```

Comment: `(?:quantity )?` would be cleaner IMHO. (Instead of matching some literal OR nothing in the group, why not make the whole group optional? You still have to be careful with whitespaces surrounding the group, though.

Comment: It is a valid and :) more correct option but that was the first thing that came to mind as I answered the question quickly. Thanks @basti1302.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this option out also:

```
@Then(value = "^order passes(?: | quantity )limits$")
public void verifyCreditPassed(){ 

}
```